# Flat an multiply arrays in Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have the following JSON input:

```json
{
  "id": 9256123,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 242424,
      "attributes": [
        {
          "currency": "EUR",
          "price": "99,99"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 22222,
      "attributes": [
        {
          "currency": "EUR",
          "price": "299,99"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to remove/flat the array

The output I need:

```json
{
  "id": 9256123,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 242424,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "price": "99,99"
    },
    {
      "id": 22222,
      "currency": "EUR",
      "price": "299,99"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I do this with the Jolt-Processor? Or maybe with the ReplaceText-Processor?

Comment: you're welcome Marcus, have a nice coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can walk by the *`attributes`* array with a *shift* transformation within a *JoltTransformJSON* processor such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "attributes": {
            "*": {
              "@": "&4[&3]", // go four level up the tree and grab "data", and walk by indexes of it to return array of objects resukt by using "[&3]" 
              "@(2,id)": "&4[&3].id"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]